# Getting xml from a dataset

Tags: c#, .net

I have a DataSet which has one table loaded with data.

When i write out the dataset to xml using the GetXml method of the dataset, i get all the columns in that data table as elements in the xml file.

How do i get the resulting xml with the column values as attributes instead of elements?

The article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx8h06sz%28VS.71%29.aspx) trails off without a proper answer

I am using .NET Framework 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach(DataColumn dc in dsHR.Tables[0].Columns)
    dc.ColumnMapping = MappingType.Attribute;
```

Quite simple   :)

Answer (score 1):

Before writing the XML, do something like

```
foreach (DataColumn column in aDataSet.Tables[0].Columns)
{
    column.ColumnMapping = MappingType.Attribute;
}
```

Although I'll admit I didn't test this. You still may get a DiffGram structured file.